# 'Path must be a string without null bytes' when piping stream to request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, base64, restify

I have a buffer created from a base64 enconded image. Im trying to send with POST to a service with fs.createReadStream(..).pipe(request(..)) but get the following error:

```
 Error: Path must be a string without null bytes
    at nullCheck (fs.js:135:14)
    at Object.fs.open (fs.js:626:8)
    at ReadStream.open (fs.js:1916:6)
    at new ReadStream (fs.js:1903:10)
    at Object.fs.createReadStream (fs.js:1850:10)
    at Promise (/Users/Sebbe/Documents/Code/leo-faq-service/lib/server/services/zendesk-service.js:120:10)
[...]
```

fs.createReadStream() takes either a string or a Buffer. If it's a string then it is expected to be a path to a file. It seems to me that fs.createReadStream() is trying to resolve the argument as a string containing a path even though it is a Buffer. Is that a bug in Nodes Buffer API perhaps?

**More details:**

I have a Node service built with Restify. That service has an endpoint that takes a subject, message, name and a base64 encoded image file (jpg, png etc.).

Now we want to send the content of the file to a third party service using JavaScript in Node.

When I have read up on this there are several sources saying that I should create a "Readable Stream" with a Buffer-object and pipe it to the request that sends it to the third party service.

Because of that, I create a Buffer from my base64 encoded image and send it as an argument to fs.createReadStream, which I then pipe to a request object.

According to this I should be able to create a buffer from a base64 string: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding

According to this I should be able to create a readable stream from a Buffer: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

And according to this I should be able to use the request module to pipe the buffer to a POST-request: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Quote from the request module docs:

> You can also stream a file to a PUT or POST request. This method will also check the file extension against a mapping of file extensions to content-types (in this case application/json) and use the proper content-type in the PUT request (if the headers don’t already provide one).
>
> fs.createReadStream('file.json').pipe(request.put(url))

```js
_postFile(base64FileContent) {
    const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(base64FileContent, 'base64');
    const fileUploadOptions = this._getRequestPostFileOptions('uploads', fileBuffer.length);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.createReadStream(fileBuffer)
        .pipe(request.post(fileUploadOptions)
          .on('response', (response) => {
            resolve(response);
          })
          .on('error', (error) => {
            reject(error);
          })
        );
    });
  }

  _getRequestPostFileOptions(resourceName, dataLength) {

    return {
      uri     : url.parse(`${this.coreBaseUrl}/${resourceName}`),
      timeout : RequestTimeout,
      method  : 'POST',
      headers : {
        'Authorization'  : `Basic ${this.auth}`,
        'Content-Type'   : 'application/binary',
        'Content-Length' : dataLength
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: What does this return `url.parse('${this.coreBaseUrl}/${resourceName}')` ?

Comment: example: 
this.coreBaseUrl = 'http://www.url.to/api'
resourceName = 'articles' or 'user' or 'comments'
Then i'm using url.parse(..) to combine the both to a valid URL.

Comment: Can you confirm whether it will be passed as a string after you do the `url.parse(..)` ?

Comment: Yes, parsing the url as such, with url.parse and literal templates are done in other places as well, and it works fine.

Comment: Any updates on this? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.createReadStream()` *always* takes a file path as its first argument. It looks like you're actually passing the contents of some binary file as the file path argument for `fs.createReadStream()`. If my assumption is correct, then you should just need to pass the Buffer as the body to `request()` like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fileUploadOptions.body = fileBuffer;
  request.post(fileUploadOptions)
         .on('response', (response) => {
           resolve(response);
          })
         .on('error', (error) => {
           reject(error);
         });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i will test that and come back with the results.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options), it can take a buffer as the first argument

Comment: @Grant yes, you can use Buffer objects for file paths in `fs` in recent versions of node, but that's irrelevant for this situation because there should not be null bytes, so that is why the file path input is especially suspect.